# What's Prigogine's equality?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology

Looking at reviews on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470089644), I read,

> entropy is explained by Boltzmann's equation (good) but it's magically connected to Clausius' inequality instead of [Prigogine's equality](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=prigogine+*+equality) (hello, 20th century calling!)

Naturally, I tried googling it because it seemed to be some kind of link between statistical mechanics and thermodynamics. I didn't find anything that looked like what this review was suggesting.

Can you briefly explain what it is and then point me to something that discusses this in depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular concept is much better known as Prigogine's *Theorem* rather than equality. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-equilibrium_thermodynamics), it essentially states:

> When an open system is in conditions that allow it to reach a stable stationary thermodynamically non-equilibrium state, it organizes itself so as to minimize total entropy production defined locally.

This is a statement about *non-equilibrium* thermodynamics, which is more general and modern than the Clausius inequality, which is a statement about the production of entropy in the special case of *equilibrium* thermodynamics.

Comment: Consider linking to the relevant Wikipedia page.